# How to install ffi version 1.11.1 on apple silicon M2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, homebrew

I'm trying to install `ffi 1.11.1` using bundle install but I get this error:

```
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.11.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.11.1' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  spree was resolved to 3.1.3, which depends on
    spree_backend was resolved to 3.1.3, which depends on
      bootstrap-sass was resolved to 3.3.7, which depends on
        sass was resolved to 3.7.4, which depends on
          sass-listen was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
            rb-inotify was resolved to 0.10.0, which depends on
              ffi
```

So I did what it asked. I ran command:

`gem install ffi -v '1.11.1' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'`

then get this error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1/ext/ffi_c
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20231230-1767-1obffxv.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi_call() in -lffi... yes
checking for ffi_closure_alloc()... yes
checking for shlwapi.h... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
checking for ruby_native_thread_p()... yes
checking for ruby_thread_has_gvl_p()... yes
checking for ffi_prep_cif_var()... yes
checking for ffi_raw_call()... yes
checking for ffi_prep_raw_closure()... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/-darwin-23/2.3.0-static/ffi-1.11.1/mkmf.log

current directory: /Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR="
compiling Thread.c
compiling Buffer.c
Buffer.c:266:45: warning: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
        return order == BIG_ENDIAN ? ID2SYM(rb_intern("big")) : ID2SYM(rb_intern("little"));
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:406:29: note: expanded from macro 'ID2SYM'
#define ID2SYM(x) RB_ID2SYM(x)
                            ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:401:33: note: expanded from macro 'RB_ID2SYM'
#define RB_ID2SYM(x) (rb_id2sym(x))
                                ^
Buffer.c:266:45: note: '{' token is here
        return order == BIG_ENDIAN ? ID2SYM(rb_intern("big")) : ID2SYM(rb_intern("little"));
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1726:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1718:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:406:29: note: expanded from macro 'ID2SYM'
#define ID2SYM(x) RB_ID2SYM(x)
                            ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:401:33: note: expanded from macro 'RB_ID2SYM'
#define RB_ID2SYM(x) (rb_id2sym(x))
                                ^
Buffer.c:266:45: warning: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
        return order == BIG_ENDIAN ? ID2SYM(rb_intern("big")) : ID2SYM(rb_intern("little"));
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1726:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1723:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }

    ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:406:29: note: expanded from macro 'ID2SYM'
#define ID2SYM(x) RB_ID2SYM(x)
                            ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:401:33: note: expanded from macro 'RB_ID2SYM'
#define RB_ID2SYM(x) (rb_id2sym(x))
                                ^
Buffer.c:266:72: note: ')' token is here
        return order == BIG_ENDIAN ? ID2SYM(rb_intern("big")) : ID2SYM(rb_intern("little"));
                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                  ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:406:29: note: expanded from macro 'ID2SYM'
#define ID2SYM(x) RB_ID2SYM(x)
                            ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:401:33: note: expanded from macro 'RB_ID2SYM'
#define RB_ID2SYM(x) (rb_id2sym(x))
                                ^
Buffer.c:276:23: warning: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
            if (id == rb_intern("little")) {
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
Buffer.c:276:23: note: '{' token is here
            if (id == rb_intern("little")) {
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1726:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1718:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
Buffer.c:276:23: warning: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
            if (id == rb_intern("little")) {
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1726:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1723:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
Buffer.c:276:23: note: ')' token is here
            if (id == rb_intern("little")) {
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                  ^
Buffer.c:279:30: warning: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
            } else if (id == rb_intern("big") || id == rb_intern("network")) {
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
Buffer.c:279:30: note: '{' token is here
            } else if (id == rb_intern("big") || id == rb_intern("network")) {
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1718:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
Buffer.c:279:56: warning: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
            } else if (id == rb_intern("big") || id == rb_intern("network")) {
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1726:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1723:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
Buffer.c:279:56: note: ')' token is here
            } else if (id == rb_intern("big") || id == rb_intern("network")) {
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                  ^
10 warnings generated.
compiling DynamicLibrary.c
compiling Variadic.c
Variadic.c:114:47: warning: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
    convention = rb_hash_aref(options, ID2SYM(rb_intern("convention")));
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:406:29: note: expanded from macro 'ID2SYM'
#define ID2SYM(x) RB_ID2SYM(x)
                            ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:401:33: note: expanded from macro 'RB_ID2SYM'
#define RB_ID2SYM(x) (rb_id2sym(x))
                                ^
Variadic.c:114:47: note: '{' token is here
    convention = rb_hash_aref(options, ID2SYM(rb_intern("convention")));
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1726:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1718:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \

                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1723:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
Variadic.c:132:52: note: ')' token is here
        VALUE typeName = rb_funcall2(rbReturnType, rb_intern("inspect"), 0, NULL);
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                  ^
Variadic.c:147:49: warning: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
            VALUE typeName = rb_funcall2(entry, rb_intern("inspect"), 0, NULL);
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
Variadic.c:147:49: note: '{' token is here
            VALUE typeName = rb_funcall2(entry, rb_intern("inspect"), 0, NULL);
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1726:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1718:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
Variadic.c:147:49: warning: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
            VALUE typeName = rb_funcall2(entry, rb_intern("inspect"), 0, NULL);
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1726:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1723:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
Variadic.c:147:49: note: ')' token is here
            VALUE typeName = rb_funcall2(entry, rb_intern("inspect"), 0, NULL);
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                  ^
Variadic.c:159:63: warning: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
    rb_iv_set(self, "@type_map", rb_hash_aref(options, ID2SYM(rb_intern("type_map"))));
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:406:29: note: expanded from macro 'ID2SYM'
#define ID2SYM(x) RB_ID2SYM(x)
                            ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:401:33: note: expanded from macro 'RB_ID2SYM'
#define RB_ID2SYM(x) (rb_id2sym(x))
                                ^
Variadic.c:159:63: note: '{' token is here
    rb_iv_set(self, "@type_map", rb_hash_aref(options, ID2SYM(rb_intern("type_map"))));
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1726:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1718:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:406:29: note: expanded from macro 'ID2SYM'
#define ID2SYM(x) RB_ID2SYM(x)
                            ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:401:33: note: expanded from macro 'RB_ID2SYM'
#define RB_ID2SYM(x) (rb_id2sym(x))
                                ^
Variadic.c:159:63: warning: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
    rb_iv_set(self, "@type_map", rb_hash_aref(options, ID2SYM(rb_intern("type_map"))));
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1726:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1723:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:406:29: note: expanded from macro 'ID2SYM'
#define ID2SYM(x) RB_ID2SYM(x)
                            ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:401:33: note: expanded from macro 'RB_ID2SYM'
#define RB_ID2SYM(x) (rb_id2sym(x))
                                ^
Variadic.c:159:63: note: ')' token is here
    rb_iv_set(self, "@type_map", rb_hash_aref(options, ID2SYM(rb_intern("type_map"))));
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                  ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:406:29: note: expanded from macro 'ID2SYM'
#define ID2SYM(x) RB_ID2SYM(x)
                            ^
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:401:33: note: expanded from macro 'RB_ID2SYM'
#define RB_ID2SYM(x) (rb_id2sym(x))
                                ^
Variadic.c:204:56: warning: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
                rbType = rb_const_get(rbffi_TypeClass, rb_intern("INT32"));
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
Variadic.c:204:56: note: '{' token is here
                rbType = rb_const_get(rbffi_TypeClass, rb_intern("INT32"));
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1726:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1718:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
Variadic.c:204:56: warning: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
                rbType = rb_const_get(rbffi_TypeClass,                          
                                    
MemoryPointer.c:165:21: note: ')' token is here
    rb_funcall(obj, rb_intern("put_string"), 2, INT2FIX(0), s);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                  ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling Platform.c
compiling LongDouble.c
LongDouble.c:24:43: warning: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
        return rb_funcall(rb_cBigDecimal, rb_intern("new"), 1, rb_str_new(buf, sprintf(buf, "%.35Le", ld)));
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                        
                      ^
LongDouble.c:38:64: note: '{' token is here
    if (!RTEST(rb_cBigDecimal) && rb_const_defined(rb_cObject, rb_intern("BigDecimal"))) {
                                                                                              
Function.c:912:22: warning: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
    id_from_native = rb_intern("from_native");

    ^
Function.c:912:22: note: ')' token is here
    id_from_native = rb_intern("from_native");
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/marialuisagako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1733:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                  ^
10 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [Function.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Links that used to fix but was unable to:

https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/814

[How to install and run ffi on M1 Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73453065/how-to-install-and-run-ffi-on-m1-mac)

[ERROR: Error installing ffi: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625997/error-error-installing-ffi-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

I also added the `libffi` installed via brew but still not working.

I also tried linking

```
ln -s /usr/local//Cellar/libffi/3.3/include/ffi.h /usr/local/include/ffi.h

ln -s /usr/local//Cellar/libffi/3.3/include/ffitarget.h /usr/local/include/ffitarget.h
```

but I get an error `/usr/local/include/ffi.h no such file`

---

ruby version: `ruby 2.3.6p384 (2017-12-14 revision 61254) [-darwin23]`

Comment: _its a long error so I redacted part of it_. Please do include the last lines of it, that's where the actual error is. Please also include if you have tried installing `libffi`

Comment: hello, appreciate the response. Yes I include the `libffi` installed via brew.  After running `gem install ffi -v '1.11.1' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'` the error I posted is just repeating. its really really long and SO won't allow me to post.

Comment: @Berkan hello posted the whole error. its a bit long. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this and it worked:

```bash
gem install ffi -v '1.11.1' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```